# Java/Spring/JDBC: changing database schema property at run-time

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc, schema

I'm trying to come up with a good solution for the following problem:

I have a number of Spring beans for various DAOs in my application configured like:

```
<bean id="productDao" class="com.myproject.ProductJdbcDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="getAllProductsSql" value="SELECT * FROM ${mySchema}PRODUCT_TABLE" />
</bean> 
<bean id="customerDao" class="com.myproject.CustomerJdbcDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Where **mySchema** is set in our properties file like:

```
mySchema=TESTDBSCHEMA.
```

I also have a Spring bean post processor configured like:

```
<bean class="com.project.SchemaAwareBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="mySchema" value="${mySchema}" />
    <property name="differentSchema" value="${differentSchema}" />
</bean>
```

Where the **postProcessBeforeInitialization()** method implementation looks like:

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if(bean instanceof SchemaAwareInterface) {
        SchemaAwareInterface dao = (SchemaAwareInterface) bean;
        dao.setSchemas(this.mySchema, this.differentSchema);
    }
    return bean;    
}
```

So any DAO that implements the **SchemaAwareInterface** can get and store the schema values when it's bean is created by Spring. For example, the **customerDao** implementation might look like this:

```
public class CustomerJdbcDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements SchemaAwareInterface {
    private String mySchema;

    @Override
    public void setSchemas(String mySchema, String differentSchema) {
         this.mySchema = mySchema;
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        //code that uses this.mySchema to build dynamic SQL
    }
}
```

---

Now, I want to be able to arbitrarily change the value of **mySchema** while the application is running so that any DAO or class that was created with the original mySchema value is updated to use the new value. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean at the easiest way? Explain it please.

Comment: Updated the post to ask more generally: how could this be accomplished. I'm looking for a solution that keeps the # of code/class changes to a minimum. The only solutions I've come up with involve significant changes to every bean or class that references mySchema.

Comment: For example, one potential solution I came up with involves writing a web servlet that when triggered, grabs every bean definition that references mySchema like: 

`BeanDefinition 
   beanDefinition = defaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition("productDao");`

and re-registers the bean with the bean factory.

Comment: Not sure about minimum code changes, but you can change mySchema from String to custom object, `MySchemaHolder`, for example, which will hold you actual schema String. Then, you can inject this object into all your DAOs. In DAO you can call getter on it, to get you actual schema String. About the changing value - I guess it depends on how and when you want to change it. You can turn this object into a `Spring` bean singleton and change it value on some http request, for example (dont think this is good), or you can rather turn it into `JMX` bean so you can easily change its value from outside